# Broadcast is interrupted while streaming udp with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

When I start a UDP stream with ffmpeg on Debian 11 server, I'm trying to transfer this UDP stream to set-top boxes via the Stalker portal. However, when I start watching these UDP streams through VLC or on the set-top box itself, the stream stops after about 5 minutes or so. But ffmpeg on Debian keeps running without any issues. I can observe that the command is running continuously. I think I need to make a configuration on the Debian server to ensure the continuous transmission of this UDP stream, but I couldn't find the right method to apply. What do you think I should try?

ffmpeg -re -i input.m3u8 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -tune zerolatency -b:v 1050k -maxrate 1300k -bufsize 4000k -g 60 -f mpegts "udp://239.100.1.1:5001?pkt_size=1316"